# nginx rewrite with trailing slash and then apply more rules

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Rewrites on different web servers are always those straws, that break the camel's back for me.

Right now I have the following in the server config:

```
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
```

Now, I need to make sure, that any URL I open on the server, has to get a trailing `/`. But if the URL has parameters, the trailing `/` is to be ignored.

A URL might look like this:

```
http://domain.tld/testing/           // is okay
http://domain.tld/testing            // should be redirected with trailing slash
http://domain.tld/testing#param      // should be left alone
```

I tried the following:

```
rewrite ^([^.\#]*[^/])$ /$1/ permanent;
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
```

But what it does, it leaves alone the url with the trailing slash, but if an url doesn't have one, it redirects to `http://domain.tld/index.php//testing/` or even to `http://domain.tld/index.php//testing/#param` when using parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this.

The part in URL starting with `#` is called fragment. It is never sent to the web server. When the browser sees `http://www.example.com/page#something`, it sends a request to `http://www.example.com/page`, and then uses `#something` for the page it receives from the server.

If the browser sends request to `http://www.example.com/page/#something`, it requests `http://www.example.com/page/` from the server.

So, you need to fix the paths in your application so that problems like you describe don't happen.